# Best way to ignore SSL certificate with request+python

Tags: python, html

I have a application deployed in private server.

**ip  = "100.10.1.1"**

I want to read the source code/Web content of that page.

On browser when I am visiting to the page. It shows me "Your connection is not private".
So then after proceed to unsafe connection it takes me to that page.

Below is the code I am trying to read the HTML content. But it is not giving me the correct HTML content thought it is showing as 200 OK response.

I tried with ignoring ssl certificate with below code but not happening

```
import requests
url = "http://100.10.1.1"
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
print response.text
```

Can Someone share some idea on how to proceed or am i doing anything wrong on top of it?

Comment: You are trying to read the http not https address and that's probably why you get the unexpected answer.

Comment: obviously it takes me to https after proceed to unsafe connection.
Even if i try to read over https in code, I am getting the same content as http. Do you have any other idea for this problem?

Comment: If you are getting `200 OK` response, then the problem is somewhere else, not in certificate verification.

Comment: Your server might redirect you to another page. Try setting allow_redirects to True in your request. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/

Comment: No.There is no redirection happening..Any other idea would be really appreciated!!!

Comment: User creates expectations based on incorrect mental model of the application? I.E: you get the wrong thing because your expectations are not in line with what your server is serving on http://100.10.1.1.